# VSCode -- How can I change the run configuration?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am working with a single python file. The first time I launched it, VSCode prompted me to choose a run configuration, and I accidentally chose *Module* instead of *Python File*. Now every time I click *Run* I get the error `python.exe: No module named enter-your-module-name`.

I want to just change the run config to run as a normal python file.

I didn't have a folder opened, just this single file. In my searches for how to fix this I saw people say "delete your launch.json file", but I don't have one. What can I do?

Comment: I was able to fix this by completely restarting VSCode. But is there any other more sensible way to fix this without a restart?

Comment: Yes. Deleting launch.json which is located in .vscode/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click **Run Python File** in the running options in the upper right corner.

[image]

The situation you described seems to use the debug mode incorrectly. You can delete **launch.json** in the **.vscode** folder on the left workspcae.

[image]

You can alse set in the **Run and Debug** button.

[image]

or it may look like it:

[image]

Comment: What if there is no .vscode folder? I only have a single file opened, not a directory.

Comment: Did you choose the `Run Python File`?

Comment: I will tell you how to replicate this. 1) Open VScode fresh, create a python file, save it. 2) Press F5, choose Module. When prompted for a module name, press ESC. 3) Now try to run the file without getting an error message like in my OP.

Comment: Hey, as I said, you use F5 to select the debug mode, so you need to select the relevant content. I updated my answer. You can click create a launch.json file and select the Python option. Of course, from your description, I think you only need to run the file. You can select Run Python File which looks like in the picture.

Comment: So the only ways to fix it once you've selected a run config, is to "open a folder" and create a launch.json, or restart VSCode. That's unfortunate, but appreciate your time!